# laravel 8 and jetsream forgot password

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

i have installed Jetstream and fortify on laravel8 everything works smoothly but [I have this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eIrd.jpg)  when entering email and password

[image: 1]

this is my form code on reset-password-blade.php:

```
<x-jet-validation-errors class="mb-4" />

        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
            @csrf

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $request->route('token') }}">

            <div class="block">
                <x-jet-label value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
                <x-jet-input class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" value="{{$request->email}}" required autofocus />
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label value="{{ __('Password') }}" />
                <x-jet-input class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" />
            </div>

            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-jet-label value="{{ __('Confirm Password') }}" />
                <x-jet-input class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" />
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                <x-jet-button>
                    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
                </x-jet-button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: `autocomplete="new-password"` On the old password field? Did you change that? Did you type in your old password there?

Comment: so I have 2 forms one on profile user when he can update his password and this one when he forget his password but i don't know where are conflicting